How do idealism and solipsism explain distinct components of experience?
In our experience, we maintain distinctions between things. There are parts of experience that can be divided or abstracted away into components, whether you are a physicalist or an idealist or a solipsist.
Now, if mind is fundamental, and there is no physical world, then everything is immaterial. As such, there is no substance separating these components. But if everything is immaterial, and there is no substance separating these components, why do we perceive distinct components in the first place?
Without some sort of physical substrate separating them, each part of experience is all part of just one stream of consciousness. There is no physical space between different components of consciousness.
A similar line of argument can be found in this article which moreso argues against the conception of a purely immaterial god without parts but after further thought can easily serve as an argument against idealism/solipsism in general. The relevant passage:

It seems self-evident that if nothing exists to separate Joe’s face from Mark’s face, their faces cannot be distinguished. They will simply blend together, and there will be no way to tell them apart. So some thing must exist to keep them apart. Also, to connect them together (if, e.g. Joe and Mark are friends; as opposed to enemies; or relatives; or co-workers; or just don’t know each other). The information has to be stored in some material. That material need not be conventional matter. It could be stored as some distinguishable structure in light, or a twist in spacetime, or made out of ectoplasm, or something. But it has to be something. Otherwise, information cannot be stored in any way that allows distinctions to be made. Nor can a mind process information in any way that allows correct vs. incorrect inference procedures to be run on that information. How could it, if we can’t keep distinct even the various possible procedures or relations? And without a circuit stamped in some material, there is no way to keep distinct even the various possible procedures and relations.


As with all supernatural phenomena, so with God: we think we can have disembodied minds (and powers and everything else), because we can imagine all the required shape and structure and forces and distinctions existing without a material substrate; but we can only imagine that with a brain: a material substrate. It is thus an illusion, and a fallacy, to conclude that things we can imagine on a physical processor, can exist without a physical processor. This illusion comes from not knowing (or forgetting) that we are doing all this imagining on a physical processor; that we need it, to imagine anything at all.

In other words, is perhaps some sort of material substrate necessary to form distinctions between things?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Almost certainly yes. Suppose I ask you to close your eyes and imagine  Donald Trump and the Pope. You can distinguish between the two individuals in your head without reference to anything material outside of your head. However, it is very hard to see how you could do that without information about Trump and the Pope being stored in your brain, which, to me at least, falls under the substrate heading.
You might be interested in reading about experiments in neuroscience, involving people who have physically damaged brains, and how those experiments add weight to the idea that your ability to envisage things mentally rests upon physical characteristics of your brain, ie a substrate.

All (philosophical) attempts at explaining away idealism/solipsism will invariably become circular arguments — as this answer demonstrates. For the idealist/solipsist all your points — brain, neuroscience,  injuries etc are in the mind (in the solipsist) There are straightforward reasons to not embrace idealism/solipsism as a philosophy but these are not from the explanatory side.

@Rushi There is an explanation for why distinctions amongst components occur as Marco pointed out: there is a substrate which stores this information. Without this information stored somewhere, why are there component distinctions?

@Syed As I said above, you assume many things — a substrate, others other than you... an objective world  — then you confirm it. Textbook circularity. Since Descartes no one has been able to rebut (philosophically) solipsism.  Perhaps there is a reason? As Ive said earlier, solipsism is a (a) pathological (b) serious philosophy.  It's a philosophical fallacy to reject it as a serious philosophy because it is pathological

@Rushi You are misunderstanding. Given an external world, we have an explanation for why we experience a separation of components in our experience. There is a substrate that stores this information. Without this assumption, we have no explanation for why we experience a separation of components in our experience. There is no explanation for distinction. Thus, solipsism seems weaker in regards to explaining this. There is no circularity here.

@Syed: Given... see the assumption? That you have so kindly italicised? You go to a movie, delight in the beautiful heroine, sit on edge with the hero in chase and on and on. You come out into the sunshine. There was no heroine, no hero, no story, no body. Just a white screen. Colors dancing on it. You went through all that because you found it interesting to temporarily forget and delude yourself that all these fictions are real. Even though there is in fact nothing and nobody there

@Rushi You still don’t get it. When comparing the explanatory power of theories, you assume each to be true, and ask if it explains X. If X = distinction of components in experience, we have an explanation for X given the external world but no explanation given solipsism. This isn’t a circular argument: it’s called standard theory comparison

Pushing solipsism again, are we, Marco?

@Miss_Understands you've caught me red-handed!

"How do you keep a Solipsist in suspense?"

OP: "if mind is fundamental, and there is no physical world, then everything is immaterial."
Indeed, this is the problem that Descartes has, first connecting mind to body and then establishing the existence of the external world. E.g.

Descartes argues that mind and body are really distinct in two places
in the Sixth Meditation. The first argument is that he has a clear
and distinct understanding of the mind as a thinking, non-extended
thing and of the body as an extended, non-thinking thing. ... that
these perceptions are clear and distinct indicates that the mind
cannot help but believe them true

Heidegger avoids these problems altogether by starting with a "unitary phenomenon": Being-in-the-world.

If the 'cogito sum' is to serve as the point of departure for the
existential analytic of Dasein, then it needs to be turned around, and
furthermore its content needs new ontologico-phenomenal confirmation.
The 'sum' is then asserted first, and indeed in the sense that "I am
in a world". As such an entity, 'I am' in the possibility of Being
towards various ways of comporting myself—namely, cogitationes—as
ways of Being alongside entities within-the-world. Descartes, on the
contrary, says that cogitationes are present-at-hand, and that in
these an ego is present-at-hand too as a worldless res cogitans.
B&T
211

Since Being is indefinable and inconceivable as an entity (H.4) straightaway there are limits to what can be established, so being-in-the-world is a neat way of jumping into the circle of existence in common sense way.

When one talks of the 'circle' in understanding, one expresses a
failure to recognize two things: (1) that understanding as such makes
up a basic kind of Dasein's Being, and (2) that this Being is
constituted as care. To deny the circle,
to make a secret of it, or even to want to overcome it, means finally
to reinforce this failure. We must rather endeavour to leap into the
'circle', primordially and wholly, so that even at the start of the
analysis of Dasein we make sure that we have a full view of Dasein's
circular Being. If, in the ontology of Dasein, we 'take our departure'
from a worldless "I" in order to provide this "I" with an Object and
an ontologically baseless relation to that Object, then we have
'presupposed' not too much, but too little. B&T
315-6

While being-in-the-world works as a unitary phenomenon there are some interesting justifications involving 'bei' and 'bin' implying that existence (Descartes' sum) already means 'being-in', residing, dwelling. So one must be in something, i.e. a world.

'In' is derived from "innan"—"to reside",1 "habitare",
"to dwell" [sich auf halten]. ... The entity to which Being-in in this
signification belongs is one which we have characterized as that
entity which in each case I myself am [bin]. The expression 'bin' is
connected with 'bei', and so 'ich bin' ['I am'] means in its turn
"I reside" or "dwell alongside" the world, as that which is familiar
to me in such and such a way.3
note 1. Reading 'innan—wohnen'. As Heidegger points out in his footnote, this puzzling passage has its source in Grimm's Kleinere Schriften,
Vol. VII, pp. 247 ff., where we find two short articles, the first
entitled 'IN' and the second 'IN UND BEI'. The first article begins by
comparing a number of archaic German words meaning 'domus', all
having a form similar to our English 'inn', which Grimm mentions. He
goes on to postulate 'a strong verb "innan", which must have meant
either "habitare", "domi esse", or "recipere in domum"' {though
only a weak derivative form 'innian' is actually found), with a
surviving strong preterite written either as 'an' or as 'ann'.
Grimm goes on to argue that the preposition 'in' is derived from the
verb, rather than the verb from the preposition.
note 3. ... Here again Heidegger seems to be relying upon Grimm, who proceeds (loc. cit.) to connect 'bei' with 'bauen' ('build') and
'bin'.
Being & Time H.54

So, surprising etymology not well borne out from the PIE roots of 'be' ( *bheue-) and 'by' ('an') (*bhi).  Perhaps more significant is the simple pragmatic utility of Heidegger's "unitary phenomenon". Nevertheless it is still just a stepping-stone to Heidegger's main concern, the understanding of the authentic Self and Being.

The question now arises: what are the existential characteristics of
the disclosedness of Being-in-the-world, so far as the latter, as
something which is everyday, maintains itself in the kind of Being of
the "they"? ... Is not Dasein, as thrown Being-in-the-world, thrown
proximally right into the publicness of the "they"? H.167


The Self of everyday Dasein is the they-self,1 which we
distinguish from the authentic Self—that is, from the Self which has
been taken hold of in its own way [eigens ergriffenen]. As they-self,
the particular Dasein has been dispersed into the "they", and must
first find itself.
H.29

